# How to test chef resource using file_cache_path

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have the following resource in one my recipes

```
download_dir = "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}\\BESClient"
task_done = "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}\\BESClient\\installed.txt"

file task_done do
  content Date.today.to_s
  action :create_if_missing
end
```

Corresponding to this I have written the following chef spec test

```
    context 'Windows 2012R2: when all attributes are default' do
    let(:chef_run) do
      runner = ChefSpec::ServerRunner.new(platform: 'windows', version: '2012R2', file_cache_path: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\BigFix Enterprise')
      runner.converge(described_recipe)
    end

    it 'converges successfully' do
      expect { chef_run }.to_not raise_error
    end

    download_dir = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\BigFix Enterprise\\BESClient'
    task_done = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\BigFix Enterprise\\BESClient\\installed.txt'

    it 'creates a file with attributes' do
       expect(chef_run).to create_file_if_missing(task_done.to_s).with(
         content: Date.today.to_s)
    end
```

This tries to create `C:\Program Files (x86)\BigFix Enterprise` directory on my workstation but if I remove `file_cache_path` variable from the Runner the unit test fails with the following error

```
  1) besclient::windows Windows 2012R2: when all attributes are default creates
a file with attributes
     Failure/Error:
       expect(chef_run).to create_file_if_missing(task_done.to_s).with(
         content: Date.today.to_s
       )

       expected "file[C:\Program Files (x86)\BigFix Enterprise\BESClient\install
ed.txt]" with action :create_if_missing to be in Chef run. Other file resources:


         file[C:/Users/AKANKS~1/AppData/Local/Temp/chefspec20180413-11784-1dp9wh
rfile_cache_path\BESClient\installed.txt]
```

anyone help how to test this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default chefspec sets a new temporary directory for file caching in every run which may not be existing in your machine. To avoid that we need to set file_cache_path. Unless this is specified your spec test will fail. You can set this in your spec_helper.rb file to avoid repetition in each spec file

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.file_cache_path = Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]
end
```

Comment: So with this change should I add the `file_cache_path` parameter in the runner or not? Should I just update the `spec_helper.rb` file and remove from runner? If I keep the param in runner though the tests don't fail I get  `Untouched Resources: file[C:\chef\cache\BESClient\installed.txt]   C:0
` I remove the parameter from the runner the tests fail with the same error.

Comment: adding in spec_helper.rb should fix, you can remove from runner. You need to include spec_helper in your spec `require spec_helper`

Comment: `require 'spec_helper'` is already there in my spec. and when I remove the param from the runner I run into the error mentioned above. I have used `RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.file_cache_path = Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]
end` in the spec_helper as it is. Hope that is ok? No path needs to be edited here?

Comment: That would be related to these two lines I think
   download_dir = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\BigFix Enterprise\\BESClient'
    task_done = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\BigFix Enterprise\\BESClient\\installed.txt'

Comment: Change it to same way it is in recipe
download_dir = "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}\\BESClient"
task_done = "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}\\BESClient\\installed.txt"

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]` in the spec. This is normally not a good idea (using the same values as both inputs and tests) but in this case it is so much simpler that it is worth it.

```
expect(chef_run).to create_file_if_missing("#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}\\BESClient\\installed.txt")
```